# Embedding <script src=> override height from remote .js

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, embed

I'm having a bit of a brainfart here.

I'm trying to embed this script ->

< script src="https://next.fatsoma.com/widgets/scripts/events.js" data-reference="5d6a9d00-5a09-4c1f-b77d-87090f186536">

into a joomla article but I need the size to be 920px height but the .js is 415px

Can I override it?

Comment: Which script ? Please, add some details to clarify your post.

Comment: <script src="https://next.fatsoma.com/widgets/scripts/events.js" data-reference="5d6a9d00-5a09-4c1f-b77d-87090f186536"></script>

Answer (score 1):

If you can host that JS locally, there's a variable on line 9 (`DEFAULT_EVENTS_HEIGHT`) set to `'415px'`.  Change that to what ever you need it to be (apparently `920px`).

However, the name of that variable suggests that the height may be modifiable elsewhere.  If there's documentation, look through that before hosting the JS locally.

**Edit:** due to the OP's comment below regarding the inability to host the JS locally, consider using some jQuery to override the value set by the external JS.

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $("iframe").css("height", "920px");
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9b39hsk1/) for you.

Comment: I have tried hosting the file locally but it doesn't work . It is basically an iframe to an online box office for selling tickets. there is no documentation provided with it.    When i add the code to my page it works but only at 415px . i can change it very easily with chrome developer tools but i can't work out how i would make that change on my site.

Comment: Modified the answer in response.